# Is possible to distinguish strings encrypted with different cryptography algorithms that are in the same set?

Tags: security, machine-learning, cryptography, unsupervised-learning

Is possible to distinguish strings encrypted with different cryptography algorithms?

If i have a set of N encrypted strings that comes from different cryptography algorithms (i.e. 100 from AES, 150 from tripleDES, etc... ) i want to know if is possible with a reasonable error that there is a sort of clustering of the strings (i.e. 111 in the AES-cluster, 139 in tripleDES-cluster) also with the simplification that the keys or the strings that are encrypted are the same and obviously without an a priori knowledge (even if there is a training could be interesting).

There are some works, papers, toy-example about that?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about distinguishability of ciphertexts and not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] is better suited for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can distinguish some ciphers based on their ciphertexts, but this doesn't work for all modes of operation.

The key observation is that AES and Triple DES have different block sizes of 128 bit and 64 bit. Which means that a 7 byte message will be 8 bytes long in 3DES and 16 bytes long in AES. But padding does also have a role in this. PKCS#5 padding will add a whole block of padding if the plaintext size is a multiple of the block size. This means that an 8 byte message will be 16 byte long for 3DES and 16 byte long for AES.

For example: if the lengths of the plaintext messages are distributed uniformly, then there is a 50% chance that you can distinguish between the two, because 3DES can have 24 byte ciphertexts, but AES cannot. Or said differently, you can find out if it is 3DES in 50% of the time, but you cannot say for sure if AES was used. This zero padding the probability is the same, but the matching lengths are slightly different.

This holds true for ECB, CBC and some others. In CTR mode on the other hand the length of the ciphertext cannot be used, because the ciphertext has always the same length as the plaintext. CTR mode is essentially a stream cipher.

If the block sizes are not different, then there is no way to distinguish them, because modern ciphers are designed in a way to be indistinguishable from noise.

Comment: I've answered despite voting to close, because the migration probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to distinguish one from another without there being some serious flaw in the algorithm. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-a-securely-encrypted-ciphertext-from-random-noise) for a more detailed explanation.